# How to display all databases along with their sizes in ASCENDING/DESCENDING order in MongoDB

Tags: mongodb

I have more than 600 databases in my MongoDB system. Whenever i run command *show dbs* it returns databases with their sizes in alphabetical order. I want to get databases in Ascending or Descending order.
Is that possible in MongoDB ?

Comment: No, mongo shell display all database name with alphabetical order in which db name start with capital letter display first then others.

Answer (score 24, accepted):

You can write simple java scripts  inside shell

```
db.adminCommand("listDatabases").databases
    .sort(function(l, r) {
         return r.sizeOnDisk - l.sizeOnDisk})
    .forEach(function(d) {
         print(d.name + " - " + d.sizeOnDisk)});
```

Or  invoke  shell with passing  the script:

```
mongo --quiet  --eval 'db.adminCommand("listDatabases").databases.sort(function(l, r) {return r.sizeOnDisk - l.sizeOnDisk}).forEach(function(d) {print(d.name + " - " + d.sizeOnDisk)});'
```

Comment: Is there a way to see this in GB? For the second method?

Comment: @DarkForce you can write javascript code based on this answer

`.forEach(function(d) { var sizeKB = d.sizeOnDisk/1024; var sizeMB = sizeKB/1024; var sizeGB = sizeMB/1024; var output = (sizeKB > 1024 ? (sizeMB > 1024 ? sizeGB.toFixed(2) + " GB" : sizeMB.toFixed(2) + " MB") : sizeKB.toFixed(2) + " KB"); print(d.name + " - " + output)});`

Comment: Note: if @Mike Shauneu 's answer is giving you an error when pasting into a terminal, try removing whitespace and then pasting it as one line, like this:
`db.adminCommand("listDatabases").databases.sort(function(l, r) {return r.sizeOnDisk - l.sizeOnDisk}).forEach(function(d) {print(d.name + " - " + d.sizeOnDisk)});`